# How to use a node ip inside a configmap in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, ip, minikube, configmap

I want to inject the value of k8s 'node ip' to a config map when a pod gets created.
Any way how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A configmap is not bound to a host (multiple pods on different hosts can share the same configmap). But you can get details in a running pod.
You can get the host IP the following way in an environment variable. Add the following in your pods spec section:

```
env:
- name: MY_NODE_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

Details about passing other values to env vars can be found in the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables).

Unfortunately you can't get the hostIP in a volume, as the downwardAPI doesn't have access to `status.hostIP` ([docu](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api))